# Pause the countdown timer on screen lock

Tags: android, timer

I am extending countdown timer class and have implemented timer but i have a problem here, i have set timer to 60 seconds,  now i will lock the screen by clicking on device power button so i guess the timer should automatically pause, but i see that the timer is pausing after 5 more seconds moving.

Eg: timer is in 55 second now i press the power button (screen off and device locked), now after long time say 30 mins when i unlock my device i see that it starts at 50 seconds.Why so how can i solve this?

NOTE: my timer is moving backwards 60,59,58...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html. There is no pause method for timer. You need to stop the timer and restart it again

Comment: @Raghunandan nope thats not the point here, i am asking why is it behaving like this and is it a bug, because if i am correct it should automatically pause on press of home button or screen lock

Comment: you might have forgotten to stop the timer in onPause() So the timer might still be running

Comment: see this http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Timer/multitimer-android/com/cycleindex/multitimer/CountDownTimerWithPause.java.htm

Answer (score 2):

## Pausing is here

#### Step 1

**onPause** Stop the timer and store time remaining in a variable.

#### Step 2

**onResume** Start a new timer with the time remaining in the aforementioned variable (of course silly, only if not zero)

---

#### Step 3

**Be happy!**

Comment: Don't You copy pasted from http://questionsgroup.com/data68/2015/07/24/android-pause-the-countdown-timer-on-screen-lock/  .You can given this link in a comment itself...Before making its an answer

Comment: @Mani I hand wrote this :). They copied it from here. Are you kiddin' me? Check my answers on SO, this is how I write answers. Also, in SO, comments are for clarifications, answers are for, well, answering to the OP. That's how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

When you press power button, your device is put into deep sleep after some time. That means CPU is not running and no code is executed.

You may consider learning about WakeLock and AlarmManager.

Comment: so what should i do in onPause or onStop? can you please help me on that

Comment: @Goofy I don't know what you should do. Depends on what you want to achieve. Add such informations to your question and also put some code.

Comment: i just need the timer to pause exactly at that time when you lock the screen

Comment: Then do what Raghunandan suggested.